# Connecting android with php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I am a little new to android and having some doubts with my new android app making.There is a website already built in php and in that we can sign in and go to a member area page in which some database elements are getting updated by admin.I need to build the android app with same functionality so that whenever the data changes the values must be updated instantly in the android app also.

Can anyone give me what are the requirements and best way of doing this project? Someone told me **Google Cloud Messaging** is the best way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is [best GCM tutorial, using PHP+mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think going through Google servers will be necessary in this case. You can directly connect to your server API and retrieve the newest values. However, you have to take authentication and access management into consideration too. If the website and the data are public, then you probably wouldn't have to worry about it.

There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.berthojoris.com/menu/blog/artikel/How-to-connect-Android-with-PHP-MySQL.aspx) you can take a look at.

Comment: registration in website is with payment so the data are not public.Also I need instant updating in android app along with the updation in website

Comment: If there are private data, I won't recommend going through google servers. You should probably look into some kind of authentication. The way I choose was to return back an `auth_code` after login/registration and save it in [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Server requires this `auth_code` to be sent with every request, or the request will be rejected. This way you can be sure that the data won't be accessible to public. And of course you have to implement SSL or other encryption method to prevent eavesdropping.

Comment: .Can you mention any tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As above answer, when will you fetch the the latest data from servers ? You have to use push notifications. In this case you can use GCM or other PUSH services. If your data is larger than 4kb, you can send a notification saying that its time to sync with server. You can call rest api to do this. But polling your server from app is not a good idea at all.

Comment: So I think it is better to use GCM